# How to solve 'Cannot retrieve length of file, path (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) ' in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, mediastore

I am building a simple music player app in which I want to fetch all songs available on the users device. I am doing this with my custom method in java

```
private static List<Map<String, String>> getAllSongs(Context context) {
    List<Map<String, String>> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    // Set up query to get all audio files
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
    };
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    // Execute query
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );

    // Extract metadata from query result
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int titleColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int durationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int pathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int albumIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

        do {
            Map<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();

            song.put("id", cursor.getString(idColumnIndex));
            song.put("title", cursor.getString(titleColumnIndex));
            song.put("artist", cursor.getString(artistColumnIndex));
            song.put("album", cursor.getString(albumColumnIndex));
            song.put("duration", cursor.getString(durationColumnIndex));
            song.put("path", cursor.getString(pathColumnIndex));

            long albumId = cursor.getLong(albumIdColumnIndex);
            Uri albumArtUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.toString(albumId));
            song.put("albumArt", albumArtUri.toString());

            songs.add(song);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    }

    return songs;
}
```

This is then handled in flutter by ->

```
class Song {
  String id;
  String title;
  String artist;
  String album;
  String path;
  String albumArt;

  Song(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.artist,
      required this.album,
      required this.path,
      required this.albumArt});
}

class MusicService {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('com.mybea.ah');

  static Future<List<Song>> getAllSongs() async {
    List<Song> songs = [];

    try {
      final List<dynamic> result = await _channel.invokeMethod('getAllSongs');
      if (result.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          songs.add(Song(
            id: result[i]['id'],
            title: result[i]['title'],
            artist: result[i]['artist'],
            album: result[i]['album'],
            path: result[i]['path'],
            albumArt: result[i]['albumArt'],
          ));
        }
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get all songs: '${e.message}'.");
    }

    return songs;
  }
}
```

When I fetch the songs from the method all is fetched properly but when I try to display the artwork I get the following error->

> ════════ Exception caught by image resource service
> ════════════════════════════ Cannot retrieve length of file, path =
> 'content://media/external/audio/albums/89' (OS Error: No such file or
> directory, errno = 2)
> This is the code where I try to use the method ->

```
      Future<void> _loadSongs() async {
        if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
          List<Song> songs = await MusicService.getAllSongs();
          setState(() {
            _songs = songs;
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
_songs.length == 0
          ? Center(
              child: Text("No Songs Found"),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _songs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Song song = _songs[index];
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint(song.path);
                  },
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: FileImage(File(song.albumArt)),
                  ),
                  title: Text(song.title),
                  subtitle: Text(song.artist),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                );
              },
            ),
```

I tried displaying the image by Image.file() and Image.network() but nothing seemed to work and gave the same error.
Please Help

Comment: Where did you get that content scheme from? And where is your code where you try to use it?? A content scheme is no file system path.

Comment: @blackapps just added the code where i try to use it

Comment: I do noty see what you use where. And you also did not tell where you got that content scheme from although i asked you to tell.

Comment: From `Uri albumArtUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.toString(albumId));`? Then why not mention?

Comment: `content://media/external/audio/albums/89` is an `Uri` that can only be used with native android code (`ContentResolver`), more: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/content-resolver